# Sketch not exporting images with correct size

Tags: export, sketch-app

I'm using Sketch 3 and I have several images that I have made alterations to. All of the images are set to 270 x 430 and when I export them, they come out to sizes such as 292 x 452, 288 x 448, 286 x 447, etc.

Super annoying. Anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: Check your export settings -- are they set to 1x?

Answer (score -1):

so create a artboards of size you want to export and add your assets into it and export....thank me later